# Нынешней (или нынешних) осени и зимы?

Tags: выбор-слов, орфография

Как правильно "для нынешнЕЙ осени и зимы" или "для нынешнИХ осени и зимы"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

И зима, и осень - существительные женского рода, неодушевлённые. Поэтому вполне применима форма единственного числа НЫНЕШНЕЙ.
Кроме того, определение, относящееся к двум или нескольким существительным – однородным членам, ставится в форме единственного числа, если по смыслу сочетания ясно, что определение относится не только к ближайшему существительному, но и к последующим, например: российская печать, радио и телевидение(из справочника по правописанию и стилистике).

Comment: Огромное спасибо!